# como cambiar el background de un toggle button dentro de un combobox cuando ismouseover

Tags: wpf, botón, combobox

tengo un combobox en una aplicacion wpf y quiero cuando IsMouseOver el background cambie a una imagen. este es el estilo del toggle button ahora con background con un color. alguna idea?

este es el codigo del combobox

```
 <Style x:Key="cbbOpciones" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffe57e31"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton 
                        Name="ToggleButton" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False"  
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />                        
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                        Style="{DynamicResource tb_cbb}" 
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Margin="3,3,3,3"
                        Focusable="True" 
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Foreground="#ffe57e31"
                        Visibility="Visible"
                        Text="Opciones"                                 
                        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">

                        <Grid Name="DropDown"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
                            x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                            Background="Transparent"

                            BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="#ffe57e31" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable"  Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <!--<Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>-->
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

codigo del togglebutton

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#FF97A0A5" BorderThickness="0" />
        <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="0" Margin="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#ffe57e31" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" />
        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Fill="#ffe57e31" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,-8" Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L8,0 L4,4 z" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#ffe57e31" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#E0E0E0" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAAAAA" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="#888888" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Recurso 'tb_cbb', muchas gracias...

```
 <Style x:Key="tb_cbb" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="img/menu_o.png" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="6" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Width="90" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#ffe57e31"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Cómo es eso que tienes un ToggleButton dentro de un Combobox? Puedes colocarnos el etiquetado completo del combobox para ver como lo haces?

Comment: edite la pregunta y puse el codigo completo

Comment: Estoy resolviéndolo pero me falta un recurso llamado 'tb_cbb'

Comment: Puse el codigo del recurso, gracias @leodev

Answer (score 0):

Mira, la verdad me causó extrañeza tu pregunta, pero ahora que pusiste todo el etiquetado lo armé y no se si lo que conseguí es igual a lo que tu tienes (más abajo explico porqué), pero de todos modos te dejo mi conclusión:

Primero: Para que el toggleButton cambie de un SolidColorBrush a un ImageBrush cuando le pasas el mouse por encima debes editar el trigger correspondiente:

```
<Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
    <!--<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#ffe57e31" />-->
    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="img/imagen_de_fondo.png"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Con ese simple cambió logré lo que me pides, el cambio se hace en la declaración de:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
```

Pero se comporta extraño, por lo mismo armé un template aparte y noté que no tienes los MultiTriggers en el ControlTemplate del Combobox, sino solo los Triggers, no se si alguien más tendrá una respuesta pero yo he quedado un tanto despistado.

Seguiré intentando de todos modos.
Un saludo.